# Assign record values at t-1 to all cases

Tags: spss

I have a data set about football player transfers that has variables such as year of transfer (1992-2019) and transfer fee. I am able to calculate the maximum transfer for each year as a variable for each player, but can't figure out how I could have the transfer record at t-1 as a variable.

If player X was for example transfered in 2019 and the transfer record (highest transfer fee) was made in 2017 it should have a variable showing that fee (t-1). If player Y was transfered in 2015 and the record back then was from 2012 it should have that transfer fee from 2012 as a variable.

[Here's a link to a sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVBuA.png)

Comment: can you post a sample of your data ? what you have can be structured in several ways, and the answers depend on how the data is structured.

Comment: What you need to do is add some sample data to your original post by editing it (use "edit" button below the post). Show only data that is relevant to the question. If possible, add the expected results to the sample.

Comment: Thank you @eli-k . I wasn't sure how to do that so I included a screenshot of the data. Hopefully that works.

Comment: do you need only the maximum transfer fee, or also the year when that happened ?

Comment: @Peak : BTW, your "fee" field is type string; it should be numeric or currency type, otherwise you may not be able to extract the correct maximum

Comment: @horace_vr I only need the maximum transfer fee. The fee field itself is a bit unnecessary as "fee_cleaned" has the values in a cleaned format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a syntax which in easy to understand, as it goes step by step. It can probably be written in a more synthetic way, but let's keep readability a priority:

```
* Sort the cases in chronological order, for each player, as we will parse the records one by one.
sort cases by name year (A).

* create the MAX_FEE variable, and assign a starting value.
compute MAX_FEE=0.
* $casenum will help us navigate through the records. Combined with the LAG function (which by default looks into the previous record) we are simulating a record by record parsing.
* start with the first record.
if $casenum=1 MAX_FEE=fee_cleaned.

* then move onto the others.
do if $casenum>1.
    *setting the initial MAX_FEE for the first transfer of a player (i.e. - the name changes, compared to previous record).
    if name<>lag(name) MAX_FEE=fee_cleaned.
    * for the same player, comparing the current transfer's fee with the current MAX_FEE (i.e. - the MAX_FEE from the previous record).
    if name=lag(name) and fee_cleaned > lag(MAX_FEE) MAX_FEE=fee_cleaned.
    if name=lag(name) and fee_cleaned <= lag(MAX_FEE) MAX_FEE=lag(max_fee).
end if.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Hmmmm - What about the `t-1 value` the OP was asking for? Must admit I didn't quite understand the request...

Comment: Thank you for your answer @horace_vr. That command would unfortunately only give me the highest fee for each year. What I'm trying to assign as a value is the record fee up to t-1. That might be 2, 4 or 8 years earlier and same for all the years after that until there's a new record.

Comment: ok, I have to admit I did not get the `t-1` part at first; edited the post now